# System.Speech.Recognizer not working in background Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to build a voice assistant and so far i have succeeded very well, the only problem is when i launch the assistant it works flawlessly, untill i alt tab out of the window, or just simply switch to another software. The speech.recognizer (its a dictation recognizer) stops working and as far as i see can' t run in the background even though my project is set to work in the background. Everything else works again after manually restarting the dictation recognizer after being in the foreground again by OnMouseClick(). (That' s what i do atleast as OnLostFocus() seems not to work for me)

Anyone that has an idea on why it stops and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Tried restarting in the background by OnLostFocus() but didn' t work

Comment: So, enabling Run In Background didn't help?

Comment: No it didn’t, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: But wait cant it just be unity cutting off the mic when running in background? Maybe that stops the recognizer? Is there an option for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable run in background option in the player settings
[image]

Comment: I already tried that and have it still on, it doesn’t work?